# How can I choose coordinate of tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, position, frame, pack

I am experimenting with Tkinter, as I was trying to place tree frames. Two frames must be placed side by side: the red one and the blue one. (see [frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar1SU.jpg)). I place this two frames with this istructions:

```
redFrame = tk.Frame(master=masterFrame, bg='red')
redFrame.pack_propagate(0)
redFrame.pack(fill='both', side='left', expand='True')

blueFrame = tk.Frame(master=masterFrame, bg='blue')
destFrame.pack_propagate(0)
destFrame.pack(fill='both', side='right', expand='True')
```

Now I want to put another frame (green) inside the red one, placed on the left side of the main interface:

```
greenFrame = tk.Frame(master=masterFrame, width=100, height=100, bg='green')
greenFrame.pack_propagate(0)
greenFrame.pack(side='bottom', padx=0, pady=0)
```

The problem is that I can't choose its position. It still remain in the top side of the window and centered.

If I change the `padx` parameter nothing change.

If i change the `pady` parameter, the frame change its Y position. Why this not appened with the X posistion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Widgets will by default be centered in their allocated space within the container.

Your code at the moment doesn't work, so I've changed it to this (I think it mimics what you're saying you currently have):

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

redFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
redFrame.pack_propagate(0)
redFrame.pack(fill='both', side='left', expand='True')

blueFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='blue')
blueFrame.pack_propagate(0)
blueFrame.pack(fill='both', side='right', expand='True')

greenFrame = tk.Frame(redFrame, width=100, height=100, bg='green')
greenFrame.pack_propagate(0)
greenFrame.pack(side='top', padx=0, pady=0)

root.mainloop()
```

If you run this code, the `greenFrame` will appear as your image shows, at the top and centered inside `redFrame`.

If you want `greenFrame` to appear at the top left of `redFrame`, you can change the anchor point of the frame:

```py
greenFrame = tk.Frame(redFrame, width=100, height=100, bg='green')
greenFrame.pack_propagate(0)
greenFrame.pack(side='top', padx=0, pady=0, anchor='w')
```

That is because when you do `side="top"` using pack, the widget gets allocated an entire strip of horizontal space. It gets centered within that space by default:

[image: Image showing side=top]

If you do `side="left"`, then the widget gets allocated an entire strip of vertical space, and it gets centered in that space by default.

[image: Image showing side=left]

However in both cases you can change the anchor point, so that your component is placed differently within that allocated spaces.

This is the code which achieves what (I think) you want:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

redFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
redFrame.pack_propagate(0)
redFrame.pack(fill='both', side='left', expand='True')

blueFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg='blue')
blueFrame.pack_propagate(0)
blueFrame.pack(fill='both', side='right', expand='True')

greenFrame = tk.Frame(redFrame, width=100, height=100, bg='green')
greenFrame.pack_propagate(0)
greenFrame.pack(side='top', padx=0, pady=0, anchor='w')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do that but with the 'grid' option of the 'greenFrame', do somethong strange. The red frame appear not left-centered, but its width seems to be higher then the the red one. Why this appened? Is there an offset ? Also change the 'row' and 'column' value nothing change.

Comment: Some of your statements are incorrect. For example, this is false: _"If you want greenFrame to appear at the top left of redFrame, that is not possible with pack. "_. Also, _"Widgets will always be centered in their allocated space within the container."_ isn't exactly true. They will be centerd by default, but there are options to change that so you can't say they will _always_ be centered in their allocated space.

Comment: I found a solution to do that. Check this video, very useful. He use the `place()` proprierty. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8-snVfekto

Comment: @BryanOakley could you share how to do that using Pack?

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra: using the code at the very beginning of your answer, you just need to add `anchor="w"` to the green frame: `greenFrame.pack(side='top', padx=0, pady=0, anchor="w")`.

Comment: Ah, makes sense thanks @BryanOakley. I did not know you could anchor any widget using pack--definitely missed that in the docs! I will amend this answer.